# How to undo/ignore referecing element transform for SVG <mask>

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

```css
svg {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}

image {
  transform-box: fill-box;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <mask id="myMask">
       <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="white"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <image mask="url(#myMask)" href="https://picsum.photos/200/300" width="200" height="300" transform="rotate(-45)" transform-origin="center center"/>
</svg>
```

Is there an easy way to make it so that the mask would ignore/undo the transform of the referecing element?

In my real use case that transform could be changed in real time by a user.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to achieve. If you want the image to rotate, but the mask to stay stationary, just wrap the `<image>` tag with a `<g>` and apply the mask to that.

Comment: Wow your comment made me rethink a solution I had tried before. I did use a <g> tag with a mask on but it would break mix-blend-mode. But I just have to create a <g> for every element with the mask and reapply the mix-blend-mode to this and it works.

Thank you!